# Detecting POboxes (form validation)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a function from another thread that helps to detect POBoxes, but it doesn't quite work as intended.

```
function isPOBox(v){
    var r = new RegExp('[PDO.]*\\s?B(ox)?.*\\d+', 'i');
    return v.match(r);
}
```

If I have the value `'Lvl 1 TowerB, 999 C G Road'` it incorrectly picks it up as a PObox.
As you can see, there's no `P` in the above.

How would I go about editing the regex to be more specific around POBoxes?

I have set up a demo Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xCQwM/

Comment: What exactly is the format of a POBox?

Comment: Maybe the `.` in the `[]` set is matching any character rather than just `.`?

Comment: Since I can't delete after I've already received answers (thank you for your time!), I've voted to close based on a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the actual match:

```
> "Lvl 1 TowerB, 999 C G Road".match(new RegExp('[PDO.]*\\s?B(ox)?.*\\d+',"i"))
[ 'B, 999',
  undefined,
  index: 11,
  input: 'Lvl 1 TowerB, 999 C G Road' ]
```

That is a match because:

- `[PDO.]\*` indicates that the first part of the match is optional
- `\\s?` is optional
- `(ox)?` is optional
- `.*` is optional

One set of strings that will match your regex is:

```
"B" followed by any number of characters followed by a digit
```

In your example, the match looks like

```
"B" matches "B"
"," matches ".*"
"999" matches "\\d+"
```

You need to give more details regarding what you expect a P.O. Box to look like in order for us to give a better regex

Comment: Thanks for your time and help on this - I've just been doing some more searching and found a regex that works a bit better. `new RegExp('\\b[p]*(ost)*\\.*\\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\\.*\\s*b[o|0]x\\b', 'i');`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, as you have currently worded it, is to replace `[PDO.]*` with `[PDO.]+` so it matches at least one char. You might want to use `([PDO]\\.){2}` though.

I'm thinking something like this might be better:

```
([PDO]\\.){2}\\s?B(ox|\\.)\\s?\\d+
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help on this - I've just been doing some more searching and found a regex that works a bit better. `new RegExp('\\b[p]*(ost)*\\.*\\s*[o|0]*(ffice)*\\.*\\s*b[o|0]x\\b', 'i');`